# como puedo obtener el valor de un dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="mad"class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">

<a class="dropdown-item">Fresno</a>
```

[image: el usuario elige una opcion fresno,pantanoso o aliso]
como obtengo el valor clickeado por el usuario?

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías por favor agregar más contexto a la pregunta? ¿Qué estás usando para el dropdown? Agregar el código que tienes y/o que has intentando, y/o la fracción mínima de código que pueda replicarse para ayudar a contestar tu pregunta.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] por favor has el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Luego entra a [edit] tu pregunta de modo que brinde información de contexto para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elementsList = document.querySelectorAll("#mydropdown .dropdown-item");


elementsList.forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener("click", function(){
      alert(this.innerHTML)
    });
});
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Esto te causa algún conflicto personal?

Comment: Sería conveniente agregar alguna explicación de que haces y cómo soluciona el problema.